# FINDSTR refuses to match EOL

Tags: windows, batch-file, findstr

Given the following piped in text:

> a  master
>   a  release
>   a  release2
>   a  some-release

Can someone please explain why

> findstr /i /r /c:"a release$"

does not return line 2?

After several hours of reading everything imaginable about the windows `findstr` command, it just doesn't seem possible to get the `$` character to match the EOL. Note that using the `/E` switch instead of `$` makes no difference. I am running Windows 7.

Can someone come up with any way to match just line 2 using standard windows commands? I will resort to grep if necessary, but I can't believe there's no way to solve this natively.

Thanks!

Comment: Of course this isn't a real answer, but in my experience `findstr` is just not worth the pain. You [can tabulate all the weirdo behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8844873/214671), but in the end installing the GNU coreutils is going to take away a lot of frustration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are not non visible characters in the data, the most probable cause is the line termination character. If the lines piped do not end with carriage return / line feed (0x0D 0x0A) characters, findstr will not match the end of the line where it should.

Try something like

```
sourceofdata | more | findstr /r /c:"a release$"
sourceofdata | find /v "" | findstr /r /c:"a release$"
```

Both `find` and `more` changes the line ending. If it works, you have found the source of the problem.

If not, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8844873/2861476) (if you have still not readed it) you will find an extensive documentation on how `findstr` can fail.

Comment: I'd suggest closely examining the output of the prior process by redirecting to a file and using a decent hex editor. Some utilities insert spaces and then backspaces in the text. Others generate LF only, not CRLF. Others use even stranger combinations - a space at the end of the line could also be suspected. And beware the unterminated-last-line also.

Comment: @Magoo, Sorry, i forget a `not` in the text. Thank you. There is a long list of things that will make `findstr` fail, both in the data and in the program itself. This is just the must *probable* cause and a way to determine if it is the case.

Comment: @MCND was correct. The problem was indeed the EOL character, as I suspected. What I didn't know was that using `more` (or `find`) would correct the line endings. The swiftness of your reply is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You mention "piped" text. I just had this problem and was searching on stack. The answer for me was, findstr /R and the echo command have some weird quirks with pipes in DOS (or cmd).

I was trying to match files ending in .jpg, so to test, my command was:

```
    echo  "myfile spaces in name.jpg" | findstr /i /r "\.jpg$"
```

But that wasn't working. I used gnu utils to find out, echo with a space before the pipe inserts a SPACE in the output of the PIPE. Since I'm very used to UNIX style echo and regular expressions I did not expect the extra space inserted after the filename in my echo test.

To fix, I added a " *" (space-star) in the regex after the jpg, (to match 0 or more spaces):

```
    echo  "myfile spaces in name.jpg" | findstr /i /r "\.jpg *$"
```

That worked great.**

Proof using GNU's octal dump command (space is 040 in octal):

```
    c:\>echo "myfile.jpg" | od -cb
    0000000   "   m   y   f   i   l   e   .   j   p   g   "      \r  \n
            042 155 171 146 151 154 145 056 152 160 147 042 040 015 012
```

Now if I remove the space before the "|" pipe, it goes away:

```
    c:\>echo "myfile.jpg"| od -cb
    0000000   "   m   y   f   i   l   e   .   j   p   g   "  \r  \n
            042 155 171 146 151 154 145 056 152 160 147 042 015 012
```

This shouldn't happen in text files in DOS, nor most commands filtered through a pipe, but it will happen if you do quick command line tests using echo like I did.

** **Another weird quirk** (at least on my Win10 version of findstr), it ignores double-quotes near the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work. /c says do literal not regular expresion. You can make it work with command line switches though. Did you look up the reference before writing your command.

Comment: Wrong - The /R (regular expression) option overrides the default literal interpretation of the /C:"string" option.